# How can I take user input for this R function?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, while-loop, user-input

I found this code on R-blogger for representing the Collatz conjecture (used the test number 27):

`

```
##even number function

is.even <- function(x){
  if (x %% 2 == 0) TRUE
  else FALSE
}


## Collatz function

collatz <- function(n){
  if (is.even(n)) n/2
  else 3 * n + 1
}


## iterated Collatz

n_total <- n <- 27
while (n != 1) {
  n <- collatz(n)
  n_total <- c(n_total, n)
  } 


plot(n_total, type = "l", col = "red", xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

`

is.even takes a number and shows if it's odd or even, while collatz performs the next step of the Collatz conjecture of any integer greater than one. The ntotal and plot steps run the entirety of the Collatz conjecture for a number and represent them on a graph. I mildly adjusted it to take user input for each step:

`

```
input <- as.numeric(readline("Enter any integer greater than 1:"))


is.evenI <- function(x){
  
  input <- as.numeric(readline("Enter any integer greater than 1:"))
  
  x <- input 
  
  if (x %% 2 == 0) TRUE
  else FALSE
}

collatz <- function(n){
  
  input <- as.numeric(readline("Enter any integer greater than 1:"))
  
  n <- input
  
  if (is.even(n)) n/2
  else 3 * n + 1
}
```

`

I'm having difficulty rewriting the ntotal step.

`

```
n_totalI <- j <- input1;
  
if(j < 1){print(as.numeric(readline("Pick an integer greater than 1:")))}
else
while (j != 1) {
  j <- collatz(j)
  n_totalI <- c(n_totalI, j)

  plot(n_totalI, type = "l", col = "red", xlab = "", ylab = "")
}
```

`

Everything is fine until n_totalI. Usually what happens without the if statement is it runs the readline statement and won't stop until something other than a number is entered. What I want it to do is ask for user input, run and print the Collatz sequence with the while loop, and then display the plot. If an integer is entered that is less than 2, I want the user input question to be asked again. How should I adjust this? I am fairly new to R.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to mess with the helper functions. You just need the user to input `n`:

```r
plot_collatz <- function(){
  n_total <- n <- as.numeric(readline("Enter any integer greater than 1:"))
  while (n != 1) {
    n <- collatz(n)
    n_total <- c(n_total, n)
  } 
  plot(n_total, type = "l", col = "red", xlab = "", ylab = "")
}
```

Just as a side note. This function still requires that you write `plot_collatz()` and then you are prompted for a number. I think it would be just as easy to make `n` the input and have the user write `plot_collatz(27)`.